# TypeScript definition for recursive function which returns the same structured object

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, casting

Let's say we have a function which should process any nested object and return a new object with the same keys recursively. How to cast it properly in TypeScript?

For example, consider the following function:

```js
function addCssSuffix(input, suffix = 'px') {
  if (input && typeof input === 'object') {
    return Object.entries(input).reduce((out, [key, value]) => {
      out[key] = addCssSuffix(value, suffix)
      return out
    }, Array.isArray(input) ? [] : {})
  } else if ((typeof input === 'string' && !isNaN(Number(input))) || typeof input === 'number') {
    return input.toString() + suffix
  } else {
    return input
  }
}
```

This function might be used for wrapping style attributes. It tries to append any value with `px` suffix recursively. If just a `50` number is passed, then it returns `50px`. For nested structures it appends the numeric-like values with `px` suffix:

```
addCssSuffix(50) -> "50px"
addCssSuffix({ width: 10, position: 'absolute' }) -> { width: "10px", position: "absolute" }
addCssSuffix([{ width: 10 }, { height: 20 }, 10]) -> [{ width: "10px" }, { height: "20px" }, "10px"]
```

Here's my attempt to rewrite in in TypeScript. We have to use interface because it can refer to itself. This one seems to work:

```js
interface RecursiveInterface<T> {
  [key: string]: T | RecursiveInterface<T>
}
type RecursiveType<T> = T | RecursiveInterface<T>

function addCssSuffix<T>(input: RecursiveType<T>, suffix = 'px') {
  if (input && typeof input === 'object') {
    return Object.entries(input).reduce<any>((out, [key, value]) => {
      out[key] = addCssSuffix(value, suffix)
      return out
    }, Array.isArray(input) ? [] : {})
  } else if ((typeof input === 'string' && !isNaN(Number(input))) || typeof input === 'number') {
    return input.toString() + suffix
  } else {
    return input
  }
}
```

However, it does not inherit the incoming argument structure properly. It's natural to expect that `const i = addCssSuffix(50)` should define `i` as `string` while `const j = addCssSuffix({ width: 50 })` should define `j` as  `{ width: string }`. How to achieve this?

Comment: You'll want `function addCssSuffix<T>(input: T, suffix = 'px'): WithPx<T> { … }` where `WithPx` is a mapped type

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPzOzN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz, it's quite impressive! I found a bug in the javascript implementation, booleans should not be appended with suffix. Also I would skip bigints. Here's the [updated version](https://tsplay.dev/WokzMW). Other than that - please do, it shows quite advanced technic and should help the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I'd take is to make `addCssSuffix()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both the type `T` of `input` and the type `S` of `suffix`, and then write an `AddCssSuffix<T, S>` [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to compute the type of the output.  So the call signature looks like:

```
function addCssSuffix<const T, S extends string = "px">(
  input: T, suffix?: S): AddCssSuffix<T, S>;
```

Note that I make `S` [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"px"` so that if you don't pass a `suffix` then the compiler will know what `S` is.

Also I'm using the `const` modifier for type parameters, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#51865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865), which is slated to be released with TypeScript 5.0.  This gives the compiler a hint that we'd like it to infer very specific types for `input`, as if the caller had used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).  Until this is released you can just remove the `const` before `T` and manually use `const` assertions or other weird magic as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680).

Okay, so here's `AddCssSuffix<T, S>`:

```
type AddCssSuffix<T, S extends string> =
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: AddCssSuffix<T[K], S> } :
  T extends number | `${number}` ? `${T}${S}` : T;
```

Basically, if `T` is an object type, then we [map over it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and apply `AddCssSuffix` to each of its properties.  This automatically [maps arrays and tuples into arrays and tuples as well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

Otherwise, if `T` is a `number` type or a `number`-like string (represented by `` `${number}` ``, a "pattern [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)" as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)), then we append the suffix to it via the template literal type `` `${T}${S}` ``.

Otherwise, then we return `T`.

This mirrors your implementation, more or less.

---

The compiler isn't smart enough to understand that the implementation and the call signature agree, so we'll need something to suppress type errors in the implementation.  We could use a bunch of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), but it's easier to just use a single call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), where the implementation uses [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to loosen type checks:

```
function addCssSuffix<const T, S extends string = "px">(
  input: T, suffix?: S): AddCssSuffix<T, S>;

function addCssSuffix(input: any, suffix = 'px') {
  if (input && typeof input === 'object') {
    return Object.entries(input).reduce<any>((out, [key, value]) => {
      out[key] = addCssSuffix(value, suffix)
      return out
    }, Array.isArray(input) ? [] : {})
  } else if ((typeof input === 'string' && !isNaN(Number(input))) || typeof input === 'number') {
    return input.toString() + suffix
  } else {
    return input
  }
}
```

Okay, let's test it out:

```
const i = addCssSuffix(50);
// const i: "50px"
const j = addCssSuffix({ width: 50 });
// const j: { readonly width: "50px"; }
const k = addCssSuffix(
  {
    a: null, b: "hello", c: "123", d: 456, e: true,
    f: false, g: { h: { i: 1 } }, j: undefined,
    k: 32n, l: [1, "2", "three"]
  }, "em");
/* const k: {
    readonly a: null;
    readonly b: "hello";
    readonly c: "123em";
    readonly d: "456em";
    readonly e: true;
    readonly f: false;
    readonly g: {
        readonly h: {
            readonly i: "1em";
        };
    };
    readonly j: undefined;
    readonly k: 32n;
    readonly l: readonly ["1em", "2em", "three"];
} */
console.log(JSON.stringify(k, (k, x) => typeof x === "bigint" ? Number(x) : x, 2))
/* {
  "a": null,
  "b": "hello",
  "c": "123em",
  "d": "456em",
  "e": true,
  "f": false,
  "g": {
    "h": {
      "i": "1em"
    }
  },
  "k": 32,
  "l": [
    "1em",
    "2em",
    "three"
  ]
} */
```

Looks good.  The compiler has produced very specific types for the output of `addCssSuffix()`, including object types, array types, numbers, numeric strings, and non-numeric strings, and all the non-transformed inputs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.0-dev.20221223#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggEwQYQM6oMoFcBmOCWAHgDwAqANDBjFISFAHYKoyogBO+DA5gHwwBeYDBikadRsxgB7AEYArKAGMQMAPwwA3jADaAaRhcYAayhhpOUQF0AXPCRpMuAiVL6rlDPwC+MG8NFxeiYWBiwAW1kodhgAHxgAAwASTTDI6O8E9USU0m8UjEy-UQBuYGAcLAYVfGkGGABDB3RsPCJiJTq2UU8gyRY2Th5BGAAiCEJR3gAKLggsEDsKVmciNTsMAEo7RBQW1ddPXjLK6pBa+qa9pzbCWYZ5xcaGMEpUA5GAcgnPza0A-CWe6PGAAMlBMHA0AshgeC0EAgEME+ckUKl+-xEInYUBAWHY9QA8gplCAAHSMDj4KCoYELTZknEILBKKDEBovGbTaQLSg6UyvGAANwaABssFArH8BPxNAEsTIFvyzFYRldHK0XNMReKoG8Dpt5VicXiCYqQEbvJQ4Ox2A0wGT8KgbXawHSQH8NDpVXZNN5DSJfFBRahYICYNNplCoDC5vDEUjPoMuNxPmCIQBCJ0AOQa2em2YiUXY7s2Zbi8WjsbhqgTyLSxYxcoVJvx9Tj5JA0gwVJ40z+AGoVrcAkGQ7Bm8bcW3YY9R8BvOVOgxuvg1c0blqAKwABk2ZQA9AeYMvV3ZRruJqNgKfVPJ19dNURptoAO74BAgAAWdl3MH9h7HreMDyL6MA4k0dSimAMDvp+P5jJekwlP+N5dKoxgPhqBzTAEk4iA0dhhKKoqULI55fsGorSKMlBKOeACMABMADMtEwAgdgACxbgAbJQUB2BwErkEaOB2DgYqhpQ3BgQh2j4HYDH-v+lCgTAVQIFABAMFACCiQqxh2CxTEMJQop2DoDGUKMTHsaM344lAoxWKONlQOEoz7sAB4AFQnuhJi+kaEEIFBMGETAxGimULZQJBDDQTA5FjJRJE0bFU4JUl9FjMxLEeaMmXYvFYWJTBnFjDxvGFcV4GleFNBCewEp1aFjXiTAknjm1DXlTAsmYgqWVlUl8lGsNI2NYpeW1RNWLeHVi0hX1SXqZp2lcHpvXZTBRkwCZDA7aNMEWfVu26KMDGFTZTE3WMjlQM5VhlL4vkHmhK7SKKUBktR3DTAAUhghLZmSyY8ICbrGJQ0wwzAhDSvwVaWIQCJIqMsj4NwXAgKM2SFukJaI8UhCUExZY+f5k6jA0oxEVgJEGWMsj06lVE0czoxKGzV2sTdASjAgvPVQLIijM5zUiYLOBs910mC9wbP4alyvzaM+C89dnmWm5gvGGzJlc6KbM6EaV1i1itmW+Lj3OQErlvR9QA)